# Inertia group modulo $Q^2$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a normal number field extension with ring of integers $\mathcal O_L/\mathcal O_K$. Let $Q$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal O_L$ and inertia group $E = \{g \in \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)|\forall\alpha\in\mathcal O_L, g(\alpha) \equiv \alpha \pmod Q \}$.

Let $\pi \in Q-Q^2$. Then show that for all $\sigma \in E, \sigma(\pi) \equiv \alpha \pi \pmod {Q^2}, \alpha \in \mathcal O_L$. This looks like it should be really easy and it probably is but I seem to be missing something. There seems to be very little information to use about $\sigma$...

Comment: yes but I am interested modulo $Q^2$ and $Q$ might not be principal

Comment: Principalness of $Q$ is not the issue. See my response. Good question, by the way!

Comment: Related: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLgV5.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have, perhaps unwittingly, backed into the (to me) fascinating subarea of number theory called Higher Ramification Theory. I think it causes a lot of people difficulty, but you can get an excellent description of the basics in Serre’s *Corps Locaux*, translated into English as *Local Fields*.

Anyway, I hope your proposition wasn’t put to you as a homework assignment, because it’s not true. Here’s your counterexample.

Let $K=\Bbb Q$, $L=\Bbb Q(\omega,\pi)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity and $\pi$ is a cube root of $2$. You let the prime $Q$ upstairs be $(\pi)$, the unique prime of $L$ above the rational prime $2$. The inertia group is the subgroup of the Galois group fixing $\omega$, and its fixed field is $\Bbb Q(\omega)$, over which $L$ is cubic, with Galois group generated by the automorphism that sends $\pi$ to $\omega\pi$. This Galois group is your inertia group, of course. Now, $\omega\pi\not\equiv\pi\pmod{\pi^2}$ because $\omega\not\equiv1\pmod\pi$.

Comment: If $\sigma(\pi) = \omega\pi$, can't we just take $\alpha =\pi$(as defined in the question?) I don't require the inertia group congruence itself to hold for all powers of $\pi$.

Comment: I was in fact doing the exercises from Marcus on (what I now realize) are the higher ramification groups.

Comment: Does this work: $Q = (\pi) + Q^2, \sigma(\pi) \in Q, \sigma(\pi) = \alpha\pi + r (r \in Q^2), \sigma(\pi) \equiv \alpha\pi \pmod Q^2 $.

Comment: What’s happening, as you can read in your text, is that, locally at $Q$, you have a map from the inertia group into $(\mathscr O_L/Q)^*$, by $\sigma\mapsto(\sigma\pi)/\pi$. A homomorphism, not necessarily one-to-one nor onto.

Comment: @Lubin: Clearly I am missing something, but the way the original question is framed (and I guess it is ex. 21(a) from Ch4 of Marcus) aren't we just trying to prove that _there exists_ such an $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}_L$, in which case $\alpha=\omega$ works in your example?

Comment: Golly, this is ancient history to me now, and I certainly don’t have a copy of Marcus. Anyway, rereading the question, I don’t see that interpretation, but with Marcus in hand, I very well might.