# Doubt about higher ramification groups

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of number fields with Galois group $G$. Let $O_K$ and $O_L$ be the ring of algebraic integers of $K$ and $L$ respectively. Let $P\subseteq O_K$ be a prime. Let $Q\subseteq O_L$ be a prime lying over $P$.

The $n$-th ramification group is defined as  $$E_n(Q|P)=\lbrace \sigma\in G:\sigma(x)\equiv x\text{ mod } Q^{n+1}\text{ for all } x\in O_L\rbrace$$
In particular, $n=0$ gives the inertia group. How to prove the following:

Let $\pi$ be an element in $O_L$ such that $\pi\in Q-Q^2$.

Let $\sigma\in E_0$ be such that $\sigma(\pi)\equiv\pi\text{ mod }Q^2$.
$\implies$  $\sigma\in E_1$.

Comment: Can you not combine the fact that $\sigma\in E_0$ and the isomorphism of $O_K$-modules $O_K/Q\simeq Q/Q^2$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300428/inertia-group-modulo-q2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find what you want in Serre's Local Fields.

Sketch: WLOG $L/K$ is totally ramified - i.e., replace $K$ with $K^{E_0}$,  $P$ with $Q \cap K^{E_0},$ and $G$ with $E_0,$ so that $[L:K] = |E_0| = |G|$, and $Q$ is the only prime above $P$.
Further, we may localise, so that $Q$ and $P$ are the only (non-zero) primes of ${\cal O}_L$ and ${\cal O}_K$.  At that point, the rings are DVRs,  $\pi$ generates ${\cal O}_L$ over ${\cal O}_K$, and we are done...

Precise reference - see Serre's Local Fields, Chapter IV, Section 2, Proposition 2 for a variant, with reference esp. to Chapter I, Section 6, Proposition 18 to show that $\pi$ generates ${\cal O}_L$.

*Edit:* As you imply in the comments below, one can get by with less (esp. without using localization, or $\pi$ generating the localization of ${\cal O}_L$) than the above.

- First of all, as Jyrki Lahtonen pointed out above, ${\cal O}_L/Q\simeq Q/Q^2$ over ${\cal O}_L$. An argument for this is: since $\pi\in Q\setminus Q^2$ (in particular $Q/Q^2 \ne 0$!), we have that $(\pi) = Q I$, for $I$ an ideal relatively prime to $Q$. Now, by the Chinese Remainder theorem, there exists $x\in {\cal O}_L$ such that 
  $$x \equiv 1 \pmod Q,\text{ and }x\equiv 0 \pmod I.$$
  Hence, for an arbitrary $z\in Q$, we have 
  $$zx \equiv z \pmod {Q^2}\text { and } zx \equiv 0 \pmod {QI}.$$
  But $(\pi) =QI$, so the last congruence means that $zx = u\pi$, for some $u\in {\cal O}_L$. Thus, 
  $$ z \equiv u\pi \pmod {Q^2},$$
  and $\pi$ generates $Q/Q^2$. Therefore, as multiplication by an element of $Q$ kills $Q/Q^2$, $Q/Q^2$ is a one-dimensional ${\cal O}_L/Q$ vector space.
- Next, for neatness, with the Galois simplification from the sketch above of the argument that basically follows that in Serre's book  (not the localisation portion), we can assume that the canonical inclusion 
  $${\cal O}_K/P \to {\cal  O}_L/Q$$
  is an isomorphism - in fact, is an equality.

Therefore, from the preceding and the filtration $$ {\cal O}_L \supset Q \supset 0 \pmod {Q^2},$$  we see that we can write any element of ${\cal O}_L/Q^2$ in the form $a + \pi b \pmod {Q^2}$, where $a$ and $b$ are elements of ${\cal O}_K$ - in particular $a$ and $b$ are fixed by Galois. Thus, if $\sigma$ fixes $\pi \pmod {Q^2}$, it acts trivially on ${\cal O}_L/Q^2$.

And we are done...

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I am not familiar with localization. The book I am reading (Number Fields Daniel A Marcus) does not introduce localization anywhere. So I believe there will be a solution without involving localization. Can you find one ?

Comment: @pinkbutterfly - Sure...  I had learnt the above from Serre's book, so that's what I thought of (plagiarism is a powerful method of proof). But we don't need his argument. But it's late, so I'll get back to you I hope tomorrow, or Monday, at the latest - unless of course someone beats me to it - good night!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - just to let you know that I referred to your comment in the edit to my answer.

Comment: @pinkbutterfly see the *edit(* to the answer above -- let me know if you have any questions/comments of course

Answer (score 1):

Further elaborating on [peter a g](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/221633/peter-a-g)'s answer, if $ S/R $ is an extension of discrete valuation rings, $ \pi $ is an uniformizer of $ S $ and $ \mu $ generates the residue class field of $ S $ over that of $ R $, then we have $ S = R[\pi, \mu] $. This is because we have $ S = R[\pi, \mu] + \mathfrak p S $ where $ \mathfrak p $ is the maximal ideal of $ R $, and so we have $ S/R[\pi, \mu] = \mathfrak p (S/R[\pi, \mu]) $ as $ R $-modules. Since $ J(R) = \mathfrak p $, Nakayama kicks in, and the factor module is trivial, i.e $ S = R[\pi, \mu] $. When the extension $ S/R $ is totally ramified, the residue class field extension is trivial, and therefore we have $ S = R[\pi] $.